# Binary polyhedron

Tags: combinatorics, geometry

I would like to propose this problem. I think that Euler's characteristic could be useful.

A polyhedron with more than 8 vertices is called *binary* if we can assign to each vertex a number from the set $\left\{-1,1\right\}$, in such way that the product of numbers in any face is $-1$.

- a) Show that the number of vertices of *binary* polyhedron is divisible by $8$.
- b) Prove that a polyhedron with $2000$ vertices is *binary*.

Comment: (b) is still interesting. Can anyone give an example of a non-binary polyhedron?

Comment: @GregMartin I'm not sure, but there exists any form to classify all polyhedra with 2000 vertices? Perhaps something like isomorphism, the idea could be to reduce to a few simple cases. Maybe graph theory, I'm only speculating...

Comment: @GregMartin A prism with $10$ vertices is non-binary.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

(a) is false. There are binary polyhedra with any number of vertices $\ge4$, since there are polyhedra with any number of vertices $\ge4$ all of whose faces have an odd number of edges. (When the number of vertices is $2k$, take a cone over a $(2k-1)$-gon; when the number of vertices is $2k+1$, take two such cones and glue them together by their $(2k-1)$-gons.) Then simply assign $-1$ to all vertices.

Comment: @ Greg Martin, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I think that polyhedra must be changed to prism. Understanding by prism two regular n-gon(up and down) and the vertices joined by edges. In this case a) and b) are true.

a) Taking the product of all numbers on each face we have
$(-1)^{n+2}=\prod_L\times(-1)\times(-1)=1$, hence $n$ is even. 
Now consider blocks of three consecutive faces, we have $6$ possible cases,
$111,113,311,331,133,333$, where each number count the $-1's$ in each face. So each block could have $2,4$ or $6$ $-1's$. If $n=4k+2$, then we obtain $k$ blocks and $1$ face remaining(with $1$ or $3$ $-1's$). Hence the number of $-1's$($V_{-1}$) is odd. But at the same time $1=\prod_{up}\dot\prod_{down}=\prod_v=(-1)^{V_{-1}}$, so $V_{-1}$ is even, contradiction. Finally, $V=2n=8k$.

b) We make a cut on an edge and the result is a strip formed by $1000$ faces. Consider the first block of $3$ faces, and the distribution

- (111-1)
- (1-111)

Repeat this pattern on each block, with exception of last one, in which we write

- (11-1-1)
- (1-1-11)

and end with $11$, the final edge, which matches with first one.